# JSF: Add AjaxBehaviour to dynamically generated HTMLInputText

Tags: ajax, jsf, listener

I want to create UIComponents with an AjaxBehaviour dynamically and add it to a HTMLPanelGrid. The ajax method will be called but there was no value binding before and no rendering after that. Please help me! Thank you so much! Here is some code:

The Ajax function:

```
public void ajax(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    HtmlPanelGrid grid = (HtmlPanelGrid) event.getComponent().getParent();
    HashMap<String, Object> params;

    try {
        ajaxSet(grid);
        params = collect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    SearchComponent search = (SearchComponent) ComponentRegistry.instance()
            .getComponent(IComponentConstants.SEARCH);
    this.score = Integer.toString(search.getSystemsCount(params));
}
```

The function for creating a HTMLInputText:

```
public HtmlInputText inputText(String id, String expression,
        UIComponent parent, AjaxBehaviorListener listener) {
    HtmlInputText text = new HtmlInputText();
    text.setId(id);
    if (!expression.isEmpty()) {
        text.setValueExpression("value", createValueExpression(expression));
    }

    AjaxBehavior ajax = (AjaxBehavior) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getApplication().createBehavior(AjaxBehavior.BEHAVIOR_ID);
    ajax.setExecute(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "@form" }));
    ajax.setRender(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "@all" }));
    ajax.addAjaxBehaviorListener(listener);
    text.addClientBehavior("valueChange", ajax);

    add(text, parent);

    return text;
}
```

The function for creating the fields depending on a list with the desired field informations and the listener:

```
public void createSearchFields(UIComponent parent) {
    String beanname = Utilities.lookupManagedBeanName(this);
    GUIHelper helper = GUIHelper.instance();

    for (Searchfield searchfield : shown) {
        helper.label(searchfield.id, searchfield.displayname, parent);
        for (Field f : searchdto.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            GUISearchField gsf = f.getAnnotation(GUISearchField.class);
            if (gsf == null)
                continue;
            if (gsf.id().equals(searchfield.id)) {
                String expression = "#{" + beanname + ".searchdto."
                        + f.getName() + "}";
                helper.inputText(searchfield.id, expression, parent, this);
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorEvent event)
        throws AbortProcessingException {
    ajax(event);
}

public abstract void ajax(AjaxBehaviorEvent event);
```

The xhtml part:

```
<h:form id="searchform" styleClass="ibm-column-form ibm-styled-form">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" binding="#{systemsearchable.searchfields}">
                </h:panelGrid>
                <h:commandButton value="Search" action="#{systemsearchable.search}">
                    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="results"></f:ajax>
                </h:commandButton>
            </h:form>
```

If you need more info please let me know :)

Comment: Why don't you just create/declare components via XHTML with a `<h:dataTable>` or `<ui:repeat>`? XHTML is so much more suitable, clear and self-documenting for creating/declaring components than all that verbose, confusing and error prone Java code.

Comment: it might be a better idea to code this on xhtml with a `ui:repeat`.